# Questions supposedly modified by someone but actually not?

Tags: support, recent-activity

I've frequently noticed a phenomenon where a question is bumped for recent activity, and it recent activity page says that someone modified it, but when I go to the question to see if it has been modified, I don't see any changes at all.  And when I look at the user's activity log, there isn't any activity reported there either.

By way of example, on the Questions/Active page, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672134/uniform-continuity-uniform-convergence-and-translation/1888883#1888883) is claimed to have been modified on August 11, 2016 at 6:06 by VictorZurtowski, but when I check the actual question, not such modification appears.  And when I check to user's activity log, not modification appears there either.

I've noticed this phenomenon a number of times.  Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: Another source of obscure recent activity is that reopening bumps, and the last user to vote is shown as  having last modified the question. You can see this in the revision history of the question-post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you don't see it is that the activity (specifically, the answer) is deleted and you don't have the sufficient reputation.

The user activity log will not show anything that was deleted anyway.

So when you see something like that, you can always assume that this is something that got deleted.

(Specifically in the linked question's case, the user VictorZurtowski did in fact post an answer at 6:06, and deleted it by 6:07.)

Answer (score 6):

In the specific case you linked, there [was an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672134/uniform-continuity-uniform-convergence-and-translation/1888883#1888883) posted 3 days ago, which has been deleted. You can see this on the [question timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1672134/timeline) or simply by clicking on the last activity. However, it is shown only if you can [see deleted posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (which is privilege of 10k+ users and moderators).

See also: [Last activity on question shows modified by user who did not ask or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75828/last-activity-on-question-shows-modified-by-user-who-did-not-ask-or-answer)

**EDIT:** One think which also users bellow 10k can see is that when you click on last activity (on the timestamp shown in the list of questions sorted by acitivity in the question next to the word active), then the url changes to an url of an answer.

For example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84587/given-g-group-and-h-le-g-such-that-gh-2-how-does-x2-in-h-for-ever) has at the moment deleted answer as the last activity. If you [click on the timestamp](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84587/given-g-group-and-h-le-g-such-that-gh-2-how-does-x2-in-h-for-ever?lastactivity) then the url changes from `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84587/given-g-group-and-h-le-g-such-that-gh-2-how-does-x2-in-h-for-ever` to `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84587/given-g-group-and-h-le-g-such-that-gh-2-how-does-x2-in-h-for-ever/84599#84599`. (Notice the addition of `/84599#84599` at the end.)

This no longer works for the question you linked in your post. (At the moment, the [last activity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672134/uniform-continuity-uniform-convergence-and-translation?lastactivity) there is retagging the question.) However, you may notice that the link in your post is a link to an answer. You have provided link in the form `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672134/uniform-continuity-uniform-convergence-and-translation/1888883#1888883` rather than `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672134/uniform-continuity-uniform-convergence-and-translation`. So my guess is that you obtained the link by clicking on last activity (timestamp) at the time of posting your question.